# How to connect to a postgres database . if the user/role password was encrypted when created

Tags: sql, postgresql, encryption, ant, postgresql-9.4

How to connect to database when password was encrypted
I had the following role created called "tester"

### create role

```
CREATE ROLE "tester" WITH
LOGIN
SUPERUSER
CREATEDB
CREATEROLE
INHERIT
REPLICATION
CONNECTION LIMIT -1
VALID UNTIL '2999-12-31T14:00:40-06:00' 
PASSWORD 'tester123'
```

I had the following database created and grant all permission to tester

**create database**

```
CREATE DATABASE "test"
WITH 
OWNER = "tester"
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
TABLESPACE = ag_table_data
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "test" TO "tester" WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I need a clarification here.....If i wanted to connect to the "test" database using user="tester"  and password=tester123.

How can i connect to "test" database because by default the password was encrypted and stored in encrypted format in postgres config files...

Is their any other way that we stop postgres to stop encrypting passwords....
can anyone help me on this ?

I just using ant script it looks like as below:

```
<project name="connect-db-test"
 default="set-name">
<property name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="db-host" value="usspvwscemtn33"/>
    <property name="db-name" value="test"/>
    <property name="db-user" value="tester"/>
    <property name="db-port" value="5432"/>
    <property name="db-password" value="tester123"/>
    <property name="db-url" value="jdbc:postgresql://${i1db-host}:${i1db-port}/${i1db-name}"/>
<target name="set-name"> 
<connnect-db/> 
</target> 
<macrodef name="connect-db"> 
<sequential> 
    <sql driver="${driver}" 
     url="${db-url}" 
     userid="${db-user}
     password="${db-password}" 
   > 
     select * from tst.products 
  </sql>
</sequential> 
</macrodef>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you show us your code and show us how you connect to the database? An encrypted password has never been a problem, it's unlikely that's the real problem you're facing now. And something else, I really hope you don't use PostgreSQL version 9.4 anymore, that's an unsupported version.

Comment: @FrankHeikensbelow I just using ant script it looks like as below
 <target name="set-name">
  <connnect-db/>
 </target>
 <macrodef name="connect-db">
 <sequential>
  <sql
   driver="${driver}"
   url="${db-url}"
   userid="${database-user}"
   password="${databse-password}"
   >
   slect * from tst.products
  </sql>
 </sequential>
 </macrodef>
</project>

Comment: You just need to use the plain text version of the password `'tester123'` in your connection setup.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i am using plain text password. i just declaring properties and set values to properties and referring those values using $ .

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am getting  the org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed error for user "tester" .

Comment: Can you connect using `psql`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes i am bel to connect using psql

Comment: I'm not a Java user, but I did find this [Connection](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) that shows what a connection string is suppossed to look like. My suspicion is that the string is not being built correctly by your script.